# How to get multiple buttons to trigger onClick() and resolve symbol view

Tags: java, android, xml

I have some Java code that I want to be triggered everytime any of the buttons in my activity is pressed. I set each button to have an attribute of android:onClick="onClick". However, I get several error codes and am unsure about what to do with them. I get that "variable onClick is never used", "cannot resolve symbol view", and "cannot assign a value to final variable q". What can I do about each one? Many thanks!!

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.Random;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final Random r_generator = new Random();
    String textViewString;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Resources res = getResources();
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.color_text);
        final String[] myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.englishColorArray);
        final String q = myString[r_generator.nextInt(myString.length)];
        tv.setText(q);
        textViewString = tv.getText().toString();

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //This casts your view to be a button so you can access its features as a button
            textViewString = tv.getText().toString();
            Button btn = (Button) view;

            if(!btn.getText().equals(textViewString)){
                q = myString[r_generator.nextInt(myString.length)];
                tv.setText(q);
                //Perform action to notify user that they pressed the wrong button
                //Do not return here. This is what caused the program to lock up
                //Maybe add a TextView that says correct/incorrect and can change that when the user is correct or incorrect
            }

            //Gets a random color from my string array and sets it to the TextView
            q = myString[r_generator.nextInt(myString.length)];
            tv.setText(q);
        }
```

And xml code...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"
    tools:context="com.example.cedric.learnthecolors.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/color_text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textSize="68sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAllCaps="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/green_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/Green"
            android:textSize="0sp"
            android:background="@drawable/green_button"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/blue_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/Blue"
            android:textSize="0sp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/red_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/Red"
            android:textSize="0sp"
            android:background="@drawable/the_red_button"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/yellow_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/Yellow"
            android:textSize="0sp"
            android:background="@drawable/yellow_button"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/white_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/White"
            android:textSize="0sp"
            android:background="@drawable/white_button"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/orange_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/Orange"
            android:textSize="0sp"
            android:background="@drawable/orange_button"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/brown_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/Brown"
            android:textSize="0sp"
            android:background="@drawable/brown_button"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/pink_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/Pink"
            android:textSize="0sp"
            android:background="@drawable/pink_button"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/purple_button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:text="@string/Purple"
            android:textSize="0sp"
            android:background="@drawable/purple_button"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you integrated the onClick inside your onCreate (or you simply forgot to make the closing bracket "}" ), therefore the buttons can't reach the method. Insert the missing bracket, like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final Random r_generator = new Random();
    String textViewString;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Resources res = getResources();
        final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.color_text);
        final String[] myString = res.getStringArray(R.array.englishColorArray);
        final String q = myString[r_generator.nextInt(myString.length)];
        tv.setText(q);
        textViewString = tv.getText().toString();
    } // this bracket here was missing

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //This casts your view to be a button so you can access its     features as a button
        textViewString = tv.getText().toString();
        Button btn = (Button) view;

        if(!btn.getText().equals(textViewString)){
            q = myString[r_generator.nextInt(myString.length)];
            tv.setText(q);
            //Perform action to notify user that they pressed the wrong button
            //Do not return here. This is what caused the program to lock up
            //Maybe add a TextView that says correct/incorrect and can change that when the user is correct or incorrect
        }

        //Gets a random color from my string array and sets it to the TextView
        q = myString[r_generator.nextInt(myString.length)];
        tv.setText(q);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
//some code
     @override
     onCreate(bundle SavedState){
     //some code
         button1.setOnClickListener(this);
         button2.setOnclickListener(this);
     }

     //your click listener
     @override
     onClick(View view){
        int id  = view.getID();
     }
}
```

In short, use click listener interface

Comment: User wants to set it in XML, and not go through bother of finding and setting each one in code.

Comment: But implementing same onClickListener method is ideally done through interface. In XML it will complicate the readability.

Comment: Don't see why. All they do is add onClick attribute in XML, and provide a single OnClick function in the Activity. It does get messy when using Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is messed up.

1. Your activity should be declared as implementing View.OnclickListener interface.
2. Your onClick
   function should be in the Activity class, not within the onCreate
   function.
3. You should declare q as a member variable of your class, and should not be marked as final.